# ajax load different page div into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying to load a div from another page into a div

the issue is that the other page div is loaded via js as well

this is the code i use

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://mywebsite.com/pageiwantoload',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(res) {
      var data = $.parseHTML(res); 
      $(data).find('#ajap').each(function(){
          $('#here').append($(this).html());
     });
   }
 });
```

so https://mywebsite.com/pageiwantoload div id ajap is loaded via js as well

is there any way to make the page fully loaded then get the div id ajap ? or any other solution

```html
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" id="ajap">'+c+"</span>
```

this is what i am trying to get this is inside a js file

Comment: Not with only client. You can have a server with pantomjs or puppeteer or something and load the page including the dynamic content but I believe that it's over killing. I'd suggest to put the whole code in a common js file and call to that function in both of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have a question. Is '#here' div  inside https://mywebsite.com/pageiwantoload request? In this case you aren't loading html just parsing it. Always use `$(document).ready` to wait for a full-loaded page. If you have dependencies between AJAX calls use `$.done` instead of callbacks.

for example :

$ajax(urlwholoads#here).done($ajax.pageiwanttolad).done(parserequestandLoad#HereDiv).

Comment: #here is in the page im trying to load div id ajap to it

Comment: In this case I think the best option is load that html on a non visible div, attach with that div a  $(div).ready  and launch any event you want.